# System.IO will copy files, but fails to update destinations file attributes

Tags: vb.net, security, file-io, attributes

I have a little vb.net script that will copy a file, set its attributes to Normal, update the file time, and then set back the attributes to match those of the source file.

```
If IO.File.Exists(Destination) Then IO.File.SetAttributes(Destination, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
IO.File.Copy(Source, Destination, True)

IO.File.SetAttributes(Destination, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(Destination, IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(Destination).AddHours(1))

IO.File.SetAttributes(Destination, IO.File.GetAttributes(Source))
```

I however I'm encountering a quite strange problem. On some configurations, `IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc` triggers an UnauthorizedAccess error, although the `IO.File.Copy` instruction worked very well.

I'm totally puzzled: I've checked, and file attributes **are** set to 128 (ie. Normal) successfully. The problem seems to be with the very `SetLastWriteTimeUtc`. But what is it?

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vista or Windows 7, you will need to run it as adminitrator, because of UAC. Try running it elevated and it shuold work fine

Comment: Thanks! But do you know the reasons why this happens? I'm not experimenting this problem on my own 7 machine, with guest account.